# How do you display the largest of odd numbers

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Im using C++. I can only use stuff I've learned in class, so I'm not allowed to use any loops or for. I can pretty much only use arithmetics and if statements. Im stuck on one section of my hw where I have to display the largest odd number out of 4 integers.

This is the code I tried. It all works fine until an even integer is bigger than the biggest odd number. For exmaple if I put in 7,9,10,5 it doesnt display 9 as being the biggest odd number. I think its because of int>int. Is there a way to make it compare only the odd int because its comparing the int even if it is even.

```
int int1,int2,int3,int4;//declare 4 integers
bool evenor(int x){//checks if true or false
    if(x % 2==0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout << "Enter 4 integers" <<endl;
    cin >> int1;
    cin >> int2;
    cin >> int3;
    cin >> int4;
    //display largest odd number
            if(evenor(int1)&& int1>int2 && int1>int3 && int1>int4)
                cout <<"The largest odd number is "<< int1<<endl;
            if(evenor(int2)&& int2>int1 && int2>int4 && int2>int3)
                cout <<"The largest odd number is "<< int2<<endl;
            if(evenor(int3)&& int3>int1 && int3>int2 && int3>int4)
                cout<<"The largest odd number is "<< int3<<endl;
            if(evenor(int4)&& int4>int3 && int4>int2 && int4>int1)
                cout<<"The largest odd number is "<< int4 <<endl;
```

Comment: `evenor()` is a weird name, why not simply `odd()` or `isodd()`? Also, your `if`s can be greatly simplified

Comment: You need to skip all comparisons with even numbers, e.g. (!evenor(int2) || int1>int2)

Comment: This problem is so niche and outside "normal" C++ that I'm not sure any answer here would be general purpose enough for the site. I strongly recommend talking to your teaching staff about this. This is particularly difficult because we don't know what parts of C++ you're not allowed to use. The answer space is artificially constrained.

Comment: Your logic is flowed. `evenor(int1)&& int1>int2 && int1>int3 && int1>int4` is checking that `int1` is odd, and that `int1` is greater than _all three_ other values, not just all the other odd values. Similarly for your other checks. That's why the `7, 9, 10, 5` test case is failing: `9` isn't larger than `10`. I would suggest reapproaching your algorithm. You don't need to store four separate variables, you don't need a bunch of complicated `if` checks. Hint: Have a variable tracking what the largest odd number seen so far is. When should the value of that variable change?

Comment: This doesn't look like any homework assignment that I know, but rather a useless coding puzzle. The trick is to figure out the right algorithm. The correct, laughably simple solution is not a thick forest of convoluted `if` statements, but rather a single expression that involves exactly three function calls (and a comparator function with a primary key of oddness, and a secondary key of magnitude).

Comment: I would do `intN = evenor(intN) ? intN : -2147483648` after reading and before the huge if-else statement.

Comment: A) Consider using an array instead of four nearly identical variables. B) `int` in a variable name is extremely distracting as in C++ it is almost always used to refer to a type. C) Space out your logic a little better, `x<y` is cramped, `x < y` makes it easier to identify what is going on. D) **Use loops** instead of copy-pasting code N times.

Comment: @tadman D) "*I'm not allowed to use any loops*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau True, but after that arbitrary restriction is lifted, that's the first thing to fix.

Comment: Minor point: `if(x % 2==0) return false; else return true;` is usually written `return x % 2 != 0;`. The result of `==` and `!=` is already `bool`.

Comment: Having multiple variables with names like `int1`, `int2`, .....  is a sign you need to use an *array* (of if the total number isn't fixed, a resizeable container).    Then you can use a loop to examine individual elements, standard algorithms to do things to the whole array/container  (e.g. sorting), etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statements are overly complex and logically wrong, as Nathan Pierson pointed out in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77223806/how-do-you-display-the-largest-of-odd-numbers/77223889#comment136140097_77223806):

> Your logic is flowed. `evenor(int1)&& int1>int2 && int1>int3 && int1>int4` is checking that `int1` is odd, and that `int1` is greater than *all three* other values, not just all the other odd values. Similarly for your other checks. That's why the `7, 9, 10, 5` test case is failing: 9 isn't larger than 10.

I would suggest a different approach:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool odd(int x) {
    return (x % 2) != 0;
}

int main() {
    int int1, int2, int3, int4, largest;
    bool largest_set = false;

    cout << "Enter 4 integers" << endl;
    cin >> int1;
    cin >> int2;
    cin >> int3;
    cin >> int4;

    //display largest odd number

    if (odd(int1)) {
        largest = int1;
        largest_set = true;
    }

    if (odd(int2) && ((!largest_set) || (int2 > largest))) {
        largest = int2;
        largest_set = true;
    }

    if (odd(int3) && ((!largest_set) || (int3 > largest))) {
        largest = int3;
        largest_set = true;
    }

    if (odd(int4) && ((!largest_set) || (int4 > largest))) {
        largest = int4;
        largest_set = true;
    }

    if (largest_set)
        cout << "The largest odd number is " << largest << endl;
    else
        cout << "No odd numbers were entered" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Which can be cleaned up a bit further:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int update_largest_odd(int value, int *largest, bool *is_set) {
    if ((value % 2) != 0) {
        if ((!*is_set) || (value > *largest))) {
            *largest = value;
            *is_set = true;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int value, largest;
    bool largest_set = false;

    cout << "Enter 4 integers" << endl;

    //display largest odd number

    cin >> value;
    update_largest_odd(value, &largest, &largest_set);

    cin >> value;
    update_largest_odd(value, &largest, &largest_set);

    cin >> value;
    update_largest_odd(value, &largest, &largest_set);

    cin >> value;
    update_largest_odd(value, &largest, &largest_set);

    if (largest_set)
        cout << "The largest odd number is " << largest << endl;
    else
        cout << "No odd number was entered" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note to asker: You didn't state whether your program only needs to work correctly for positive numbers or if it needs to be able to handle negative numbers. This solution works correctly for positive numbers.

Comment: @NathanPierson why would this not work for negative numbers?

Comment: As `negative_number < 0` (`largest` is 0)

Comment: Specifically, it won't work if the largest odd number is negative.